Solving math equations for X in real-time
Is there an easy way to setup an if/else statement that will solve for X in the screenshot below, or is the Solver add-in the best way to go with this. I have a lot of equations to mock up so wanted to find the easiest method of dynamically solving for an unknown variable.
I know some scripting but do not know VB or C++. I just want to see if there was an easy/replicatable  way to do this.

(Volume 1)*(Pressure 1) = (Volume 2)*(Pressure 2)


how would you do it with math?  do you just want to find the value above or below if 'x'.  You need to explain how one would figure it out in words so we can help with the appropriate formula.

My bad. I just added the equation for this. Both sides will equal the same thing because they are proportional to each other. So in some cases multiplication will be needed and in some, subtraction.

I wasn't sure about the logic and had no clear understanding of how to accomplish the output, however I came up with the following formula and the complete credit goes to Scott Craner Sir, because of the idea and algorithm sir came up with.


The following formula works with MS365 and it is one single dynamic array formula which spills out the output for the whole array. Thus, Solving for x.
• Formula used in cell E2
=BYROW(A2:D6,LAMBDA(Σ,
 LET(
     _a, TAKE(Σ,,2),
     _b, DROP(Σ,,2),
     _x, PRODUCT(FILTER(_a,1-ISERROR(--_a))),
     _y, PRODUCT(FILTER(_b,1-ISERROR(--_b))),
     IF(_x<_y, _y/_x,_x/_y))))



Solve for x.
We can use two formulas with internal IFs to replace x with 1.  One that puts one side in the divisor and another that is the reciprocal.
=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:B2,"x"),(C2*D2)/(IF(A2="x",1,A2)*IF(B2="x",1,B2)),(A2*B2)/(IF(C2="x",1,C2)*IF(D2="x",1,D2)))



Name cells as the following:
A1 : Volume 1
B1 : Pressure 1
C1 : Volume 2
D1 : Pressure 2
E1 : Missing Value

Select cells from A1 to E1, then press Ctrl + T, and check:

My table has headers

checkbox in the popup window.
Copy and paste the following equation in E2:
=IF([@[Volume 1]]="x", ([@[Volume 2]]*[@[Pressure 2]])/[@[Pressure 1]], 
IF([@[Pressure 1]]="x", ([@[Volume 2]]*[@[Pressure 2]])/[@[Volume 1]], 
IF([@[Volume 2]]="x", ([@[Volume 1]]*[@[Pressure 1]])/[@[Pressure 2]], 
IF([@[Pressure 2]]="x", ([@[Volume 1]]*[@[Pressure 1]])/[@[Volume 2]], ""))))

Then, press Enter.
Now, enter your values from A to D, and x will be evaluated in E
